# Accessing variables (of some class) inside a PHP class

Tags: class, variables, object, types, casting

I implemented a class like this:

```
class ClassRoom
{
  public $desired_connection;  // variable of type DesiredConnection

  //Constructor
  public function __contruct()
  {
    $this->desired_connection = new DesiredConnection(); //Initialize
  }

  public function save(){   
    //Save Desired Connection
    $this->desired_connection->saveDesiredConnection();  
  }
}
```

Upon calling $classroom->save(), runtime does not recognize $this->desired_connection as DesiredConnection object and throws this error:

"Call to a member function save() on a non-object."

When I output, gettype($classroom->desired_connection), it outputs NULL.

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `__construct` function is named appropriately:

```
public function __construct() {
  // ...
}
```

PHP will only recognize magic functions that match the names it's looking for!

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe that this was a typo!

Comment: Happens to all of us :^) Cheers!